# How to convert a XML with different attribute schemas into a dataframe in scala

Tags: xml, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I have the following XML file, each table has different attribute names and the schema's are different for each of these at_name's. It's a very long file, I have only posted only the a few lines here:

```
<CATALOG>
    <TABLE at_name="Furniture">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW typeid="0" caseid="0" key="1" code="0"/>
            <ROW typeid="1" caseid="0" key="1" code="0"/>
            <ROW typeid="1" caseid="1" key="1" code="0"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE at_name="Cutlery">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW cutleryTypeid="0" color="Blue" code="0"/>
            <ROW cutleryTypeid="0" color="Blue" code="0"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE at_name="Apparel">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW ApparelTypeid="1" color="Blue" barcode="0111"/>
            <ROW ApparelTypeid="0" color="Blue" barcode"1122"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
<CATALOG>
```

To read the XML I have defined custom schemas for each of the attribute's in scala, this one is for furniture:

```
//Function to read XML furniture 
def getFurniture: StructType = {

    val rowType = new StructType()
      .add("_typeid", StringType)
      .add("_caseid", StringType)
      .add("_key", StringType)
      .add("_code", StringType)


    val rowDataType = new StructType()
      .add("ROW", ArrayType(rowType))

    val furniType = new StructType()
      .add("_at_name", StringType)
      .add("ROWDATA", rowDataType)

    furniType
  }

//In the main class
val cabinetDF = session.read
      .option("rootTag", "CATALOG")
      .option("rowTag", "TABLE")
      .schema(schema)
      .xml(filePath)
      .filter("_at_name = 'Furniture'")
```

I get this data frame when I run this code:

```
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|_at_name |ROWDATA                                     |
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|Furniture|{[{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}]}|
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The output I want is:

[image]

I tried to use explode to convert the above data frame but it does not work because I have used struct type which gives some extra brackets. Is there any other way I can get the desired output?